# LSI Raid controller: identifying failing hard disk (MegaCLI)

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid, megacli

Info:
I have a LSI 9265-8i controller. It's been running pretty well for two years. More recently it looks like a drive may be failing - no errors reported and no media issues reported when viewing "MegaRAID Storage Manager". Performance on one of the virtual drives is quite bad.
I ran "MegaCli -AdpEventLog -GetLatest 1000 -f events1000.log -aALL" and looked at the output. There are some "unexpected sense" logs around two months ago. I have no idea what they mean.
Code: 0x00000071
Class: 0
Locale: 0x02
Event Description: Unexpected sense: PD 09(e0xfc/s0) Path 4433221103000000, CDB: 28 00 9d 96 dc 89 00 00 77 00, Sense: 3/11/00

## Event Data:

Device ID: 9
Enclosure Index: 252
Slot Number: 0
CDB Length: 10
CDB Data:
0028 0000 009d 0096 00dc 0089 0000 0000 0077 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 Sense Length: 18
Sense Data:
00f0 0000 0003 009d 0096 00dc 0089 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

So to my question:
How do I use MegaCLI to understand which drive is failing if any?
Are there good reasonably-priced tools I can purchase to tell me something useful?

Now for my moan:
Why don't LSI include decent reporting and diagnostics into their management tools?

Comment: The LSI is cheap on that. I had to use the megaraid utility, in the eventlog it was showing the HDD serial number. (thus I used it to ID the faulty disk)

Comment: Thanks yagmoth555, I also used MegaRaid to get the SN's. The "path" in my original post (4433221103000000) is the SN.

Comment: You can look at the SMART data for any physical disk on LSI controller: `smartctl -d megaraid,0 -a /dev/sda`, where `0` is location of the PD (from megacli output) and `/dev/sda` is any virtual drive available to the system.